# Slimming down nested array Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to port over the functionality of

```
random.sample(range(0, 6), 2)
```

to javascript from python using this function:

```
function randomIntFromInterval(range, n) {
  var sample = [];
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    sample.push(range.splice(Math.random()*range.length,1));
  }

  return sample;
}
```

However I am getting this result:

```
[[[2], [3]], [[1], [2]], [[6], [1]], [[4], [3]], [[2], [1]], [[6], [2]], [[0], [2]], [[1], [6]], [[1], [3]], [[6], [5]]]`
```

Instead of something like this:

```
[[2, 3], [1, 2], [6, 1], [4, 3], [2, 1], [6, 2], [0, 2], [1, 6], [1, 3], [6, 5]]
```

Any Tips?

EDIT: this is the code im using to call the function

```
var randomizedOff = []
while (z < 10){
randx = randomIntFromInterval([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],2)
  randomizedOff.push(randx)
  z++
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? I don't get anything like that when I use `randomIntFromInterval([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 10)`

Comment: My result is `[[6],[0],[1],[5],[4],[2],[3],[],[],[]]`

Comment: updated post. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slice()` returns an array of all the elements that were removed from the array. So if you remove one element, you get an array with one element.

You can simply index it with `[0]` to extract the element from the array.

```
function randomIntFromInterval(range, n) {
  var sample = [];
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    sample.push(range.splice(Math.random()*range.length,1)[0]);
  }

  return sample;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using `splice` which always returns an array use `[0]` to get the element

```
function randomIntFromInterval(range, n) {
  var sample = [];
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    sample.push(range.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * range.length), 1)[0]);
  }
  return sample;
}
```

It is unclear if the example output is multiple calls of the function in an array or just one

Comment: They're using slice because they don't want to return the same number twice. So they remove it from the array when selecting it.

Comment: @Barmar if that's what they want they can use the pop method. I don't think slice does that

Comment: for my use cases the randomized digits cannot be the same

Comment: I'll edit it then

Comment: @SollyBunny pop always removes from the end, you can't get a random index.

Comment: @sollybunny thank you for taking the time. i appreciate you both